# How do you do Paul Erdős' name in LaTeX

Tags: accents

Paul Erdős' name has an "o" which has something a bit like an umlaut but not quite the same. How do you do this symbol in LaTeX?

Comment: Try the command `Paul Erd\H{o}s` or use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` -- you can type it directly then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly input the ő if you use the *utf8* inputenc encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 %other useful packages
 Pál Erdős
```

Should work.

Otherwise you can use the `\H` command:

`P\'al Erd\H{o}s` should do the trick.

EDIT: I incorporated the correct name, suggested by @egreg

Comment: And if you want to use the *real* name, `Pál Erdős` or `P\'al Erd\H{o}s`

Comment: @egreg -- and if i remember correctly what i learned about hungarian, the surname comes first.  (though he traveled and published enough outside hungary that the name was usually rendered western style.)